# How to install self signed certificate on Apache in Linux?

Tags: linux, openssl

Where certificate files being created while using openssl? How to install custom generated certificate on Apache https?

```
root@ubuntu:/# openssl req \
>   -x509 -nodes -days 365 \
>   -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout mycert.pem -out mycert.pem
Generating a 1024 bit RSA private key
......++++++
........................++++++
writing new private key to 'mycert.pem'
-----

root@ubuntu:/# openssl pkcs12 -export \
>   -out mycert.pfx -in mycert.pem \
>   -name "My Certificate"
Enter Export Password:
Verifying - Enter Export Password:
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl

```
SSLCertificateFile    /etc/ssl/certs/mycert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/mycert.key # ???
```

As far as I understand I should include in */etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl* directives which define SSL certificated. What folder used to store generated certificates *mycert.pem*? Where to get *mycert.key* file?

---

Tried to generate

```
openssl req -new -sha1 -newkey rsa:1024 -nodes -keyout mycert.key -out localhost.csr -subj '/O=Company/OU=Department/CN=localhost
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you get a Self Signed Cert made and set up:

http://www.akadia.com/services/ssh_test_certificate.html

It's pretty straight forward. It looks like you skipped the Step 2 and need to change the way you're doing step 4.